# How to redirect_to and keep object's attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling

- I have two models, `articles` and `comments`.
- `articles` have many `comments`.
- `comments` cannot be empty strings.

On `articles#index`, I have a couple of text fields (username, comment_text, etc.) below each article for the user to leave a comment.

When a user submits an empty comment, rails does its validation job and the save method fails on `comments#create`. I now want to go back to `articles#index` and display the appropriate error messages. Here is where I need some help.

It seems I only have two choices, none of which satisfies me. Either:

1. I `render` `articles#index`'s view from `comments#create`, but then I have to somehow duplicate all the code of `articles#index` and the user stays on an url that's not appropriate (`comments#create` while they have `articles#index` rendered)
2. Or I `redirect_to` `articles#index` but then I lose my comment object. Using flash messages only will not do it for me here, I really need to keep my object with all attributes

Is there a way to go back to `articles#index` while keeping my comment object? What's the best practice in this usecase?

PS: I wish not to use any javascript/ajax here.

Comment: You could use a [session](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session) variable

Comment: I would agree with Rocco - set a session variable - index can check to see if the session variable is set and use the information accordingly, setting the session variable to nil once it is done with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think a legit way would be doing this setting a temporary session variable and then clear it once you've loaded it in the next request.

Another way of achieving this would be passing the params in the next request in the query string.
like so:

```
redirect_to(foo_path, bar_attributes)
```

where `bar_attributes` would be a hash.